# Objects var names inside arrays in JavaScript

Tags: arrays, object, javascript-objects

Is it possible to add a variable name of each objects inside in an array in JavaScript. I mean something like this (pseudocode):

```
var arr = [ 
    object 1 name { 
        key1: "some value",
        key2: "some value",
        key3: "some value"
    }, 
    object 2 name { 
        key1: "some value",
        key2: "some value",
        key3: "some value"
    }
]
```

or it's only possible to be like this :

```
var arr = [ 
    { 
        key1: "some value",
        key2: "some value",
        key3: "some value" 
    },
    { 
        key1: "some value",
        key2: "some value",
        key3: "some value"
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to say is, can I give a name for each object element inside an array?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself wishing to name members of an array (presumably for lookup by name later), you should probably use a dictionary (ie. an object) instead.

```
var data = { 
    object1: {
        key1: "some value",
        key2: "some value",
        key3: "some value"
    },
    object2: { 
        key1: "some value",
        key2: "some value",
        key3: "some value"
    }
};
```

Then, you can access object2 like this:

`var object2 = data.object2;` or `var object2 = data['object2'];`

On the other hand, you can access members of an array by their index like this:

`var object2 = arr[1];`

Comment: this is the best way to go - also note: `Object.values(data)` returns an array holding all the values of your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to have an array, you can do so by naming each item in that array (your choice if you want the sub-data at the same level, or nested).

```
var data = [
  {
    id: "John",
    data: {
      key1: "some value",
      key2: "some value",
      key3: "some value"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "Susan",
    data: { 
      key1: "some value",
      key2: "some value",
      key3: "some value"
    }
  }
];
```